# Is it possible to get a list with all video ids of videos analyzed?

Tags: azure-video-indexer

I'm using Azure Video Analyzer. For video's already analyzed, I can look up the video id and then use Python to get the results in json format, that works. But I want to get all the json files for all the video's analyzed with the video analyzer. To accomplish this I need a list with all the video ids.

Is it possible to get all the video ids automatically?
I'm using the trial version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [List Videos](https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/api-details#api=Operations&operation=List-Videos) API to list all the videos in your account.

Answer (score 0):

Visit our developer portal to explore all our APIs - [developer portal](https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/api-details#api=Operations&operation=Get-Account-Access-Token)